# Remove specific line in file with sed, not just content in the line

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to remove a specific line from the file, not just the content of the line. I've been using

`sed -i 's/foo//' /tmp/test`

to remove lines with foo in them from below file

```
bar
foo
foo
bar
```

but that results in

```
bar


bar
```

instead, how can I get rid of the new lines as well?

Comment: try: `sed -i /foo/d file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
sed -i '/foo/d' /tmp/test
```

Check [GNU sed doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-d-_0028delete_0029-command)